# images on CGI or HTML files

Tags: perl, imageview, localhost, cgi

Recently, I run small local host for myself, but when I write a CGI file or HTML file, it shows everything except images. Does everyone know what happen and what shall I do?

Comment: Insufficient information to give you an answer. Can I suggest you include some sample text, and some links to images that aren't working? Most likely causes are path  and permissions.

Comment: my one part of code is as following:  #!/usr/bin/perl use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use DBI;
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print first();
print myform();
print second();

sub myform{
    return <<B;

    <form action='' method='post'>
        <img src="images/img0001.gif" id="Shape1" align="top" alt="" title="" border="0" width="1344" height="126"></div>           and my images path is pubic_html/cgi-bin/images and my file is in pubic_html/cgi-bin

Comment: Please edit your question to include any errors from your webserver's error log.

Comment: I don't have any error. I only cannot see my pictures in browser and instead there is an icon with broken file picture. I can see other items there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to answer because you haven't given us anywhere near enough information. But your code does give one potential clue.

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use DBI;

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print first();
print myform();
print second();

sub myform {
  return <<B;
<form action='' method='post'>
  <img src="images/img0001.gif" id="Shape1" align="top" alt="" title="" border="0" 
       width="1344" height="126">
  ...
</form>
B
}
```

You try to serve the image from `images/img0001.gif`. But that's relative to the current directory - which will almost certainly be `/cgi-bin` when this code is executed. And most web servers are configured so that any files under `/cgi-bin` are assumed to be CGI programs.

So I'd guess that your web server is trying to execute your image file. Which isn't going to work. What's in the web server error log?

Move any static files (html, images, css) out of the `/cgi-bin` directory.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your response.I transferred the image directory to upper folder and include the path in my cods(src = "../../images/logo.jpg"), but it didn't affect. Also there is limitation to send you all code, however, it doesn't matter. If it will be even one line code like "Hello World" program and including a picture. It shows only "Hello world" not the image. May problem will be in apache2 configuration?

Comment: Why not just use `<img src="/images/logo.jpg">`? What do you get in your web server error log?

Comment: It doesn't work. I put my image folder in home directory and outside of public_html folder and it doesn't work too.

Comment: Please read [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). I'd really like to help, but you're not giving me much to go on. Please update your question with a complete program that doesn't work how you expect it to. Please also add some sample lines from your web server error log.

Comment: Hi dave, Following is a sample code which doesn't work:         #!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print "Hello, World.";

print "<img src='logo.jpg'>";

Comment: From my previous comment - "Please update your question with a complete program that doesn't work how you expect it to. Please also add some sample lines from your web server error log." If you're going to ignore my advice, then I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks Dave, your guide help me to search for another place to put my image and I solved my problem.I made cgi-bin and site in home,but apache look for images in default place in var/www

Comment: Then the Apache error log would have contained errors telling you the complete path to the files that it couldn't find. If you had read the log you could have saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally my problem solved. As my cgi-bin folder was in home/username/public_html, I put my images folder in home directory. But when I saved my images in var/www/ , everything was corrected.