# How can I display my image?

Tags: perl

I have no idea why it doesn't work as I am trying to upload it to a certain directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl use CGI qw(:standard);
#use strict;

my $cgi         = new CGI;
my $upload_dir  = '/home/...';

my $max_files   = 3; #maximum number of files allowed.
print $cgi->header(-type => 'text/html');
for (my $count = 1; $count <= $max_files; $count++){
    my $filen    = "file".$count;
    my $file     = $cgi->param($filen);
    my $filename = $file;
    $filename    =~ s/^.*(\\|\/)//g;

    if($file)
    {
        open(OUT, ">$upload_dir/$filename") || die print "Fail to upload: $!";
        while(<$file>) {
            print OUT;
        }
        close(OUT);
    }
}

print "File(s) Uploaded\n";

print qq~
        <HTML>
       <head></head>
       <body>
       <h1>
       <img src="path/to/myimage">
       My Name is blabla.
       </h1>
       </body>
       </HTML> ~;
```

I got my image file uploaded to the document root, but for some reason, the page can't display the file.

Comment: Please use proper code formatting for your code blocks. You can do this by highlighting the entire block and clicking the `{}` icon in the editor, or by indenting every line by four spaces.

Comment: Where, exactly, on the server do you upload the image file to? Are you sure that it is somewhere accessible to the web server? What, exactly, is the URL you are using for the image? Is anything written to the web server error log? You should see an error telling which file it fails to find.

Comment: Some of the [discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614013/images-on-cgi-or-html-files/26631616) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what the script is supposed to do is upload a file to a certain directory.
You say that it does so, but the page does not display the file.

So the only problem can be

```
<img src="path/to/myimage">
```

Unfortunately, it seems you have changed the code here, or it is entirely clear why it is not working:

note 'myimage' is not the name of the file you wrote to in the script, so this would not work.

If you have it correct in your script but posted it here differently, another reason could be the path.

"path/to/" as the path may not be the path you mean, you store it in '/home/...'
  ( wherever that is exactly ), and access it from the path of the script. So right now it should look for a subdirectory "path/to" and a file 'myimage'.

Try giving an absolute path ( /home/user/image_directory/file1 ) or relative path from script path ( ../image_directory/file1 ) instead.

Good luck

For lack of reputation, I cannot comment :/

If the images are fine when opened with another program,
the problem should be either permissions or the path.

Did you check permissions on the directory and the files? Can they be read?

To double-check, try accessing another image in same path, or another image in another path, and so on. html does not exactly tell you much usually about why it failed to load so you have to experiment.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The path itself works but all I see is just an X on the page. No image whatsoever appears.

Comment: Does "the path works" also mean "the uploaded image file is fine" ? Otherwise, you may need binmode when writing, though afaik mostly in windows [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html)